# Why do I get a CORS error when using the custom domain name for my Cloudfront distribution?

Tags: cors, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I have an AWS Cloudfront distribution with an S3 origin.  I am trying to make a simple fetch request to get an image from the CDN.  When I use the default Cloudfront url, the request works fine.  However, when I use the custom domain that is configured for the distribution, it fails with a CORS error:

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I've followed everything in this [article](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/no-access-control-allow-origin-error) to ensure that the s3 origin is returning the correct CORS headers and that the Cloudfront distribution is forwarding the correct CORS headers.  It only fails when using the alternate domain.

Comment: In CloudFront, are using S3 Origin or Custom Origin? second thing, what bucket policy you added in S3 bucket to enable CORS?

Comment: @AnkushJain, I am using an S3 Origin and this is the cors config:


[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Updating CORS Policy at S3 Origin

First thing you need to replace the CORS policy for the S3 bucket with the below one:

```json
[{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "HEAD",
        "POST",
        "PUT
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "http://www.your-domain.com"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
    ]
}]
```

### Configure the CloudFront distribution to forward the appropriate headers to the origin server

After you set up a CORS policy on your origin server, configure your CloudFront distribution to forward the origin headers to the origin server. If your origin server is an Amazon S3 bucket, then configure your distribution to forward the following headers to Amazon S3:

- Access-Control-Request-Headers
- Access-Control-Request-Method
- Origin

To forward the headers to the origin server:

- Open your distribution from the [CloudFront console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).
- Select an existing behavior, and then choose Edit.
- Under **Cache key and origin requests**, choose **Cache policy and origin request policy**.
- Then, for *Origin request policy*, choose **CORS-S3Origin** as per the below screenshot.
- Choose **Save changes**.

[image]

Hope this should help!

Comment: I have tried updating my cors policy and it still does not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you try again with the updated steps?

Comment: Is there a good reason to expose the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header?